# Transferring data into an open workbook from a closed workbook without having to specify the file path, considering that both are in the same folder

Tags: vba, excel

How can I modify the below code to do so? I tried my luck with ThisWorkbook.Path. New to VB, any help would be much appreciated.

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
Dim WB1 As Workbook
Dim WB2 As Workbook

Set WB1 = ActiveWorkbook
Set WB2 = Workbooks.Open("C:\Users\joseph\Desktop\Required Files\Almost final\ RawData.xlsm")

WB1.Sheets("CR Details").Columns("A:AW").Value = WB2.Sheets("sheet1").Columns("A:AW").Value

WB2.Close
End Sub
```

Comment: Where is the code running?  In WB1, or in some other workbook?

Comment: WB1, the workbook into which data from WB2 has to be inserted.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try:

```
Set WB2 = Workbooks.Open(WB1.Path & "\RawData.xlsm")
```

if WB2 is in the same folder as WB1.

If the macro is running from a third (separate) workbook in the same location as WB2 then:

```
Set WB2 = Workbooks.Open(ThisWorkbook.Path & "\RawData.xlsm")
```